# Save data in Form2 with Account ID in 1 column to see who's owning that data

Tags: c#, mysql

I ideally wanted to make so that when the user is logged in and have gone to form2. That when they write  new data and press save to save the data in the mysql database **With their account ID in 1 column** but  I couldn't figure out how to do that so I am turning here for help.

Form1 relevant code:

```
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=SERVERIP;port=3306;database=DATABASE;uid=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='" + this.user_txt.Text + "' AND pass='" + this.password_txt.Text + "';", con);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader;

            con.Open();

            MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;

            while (MyReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                this.Hide();
                var form1 = new Form2();
                form1.Show();
            }
```

Form2 relevant code:

```
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=SERVERIP;port=3306;database=DATABASE;uid=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD"))
        {
            con.Open();

           using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into info(Datum,Timmar,Rast) Values(@Datum,@Timmar,@Rast)", con))
            {
               DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", now);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timmar", textBox2.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rast", textBox3.Text);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               MessageBox.Show("Sparat!");
               con.Close();
            } 
        }
```

So what I want todo is to add account id with that information from form2 into the database.
something like:

```
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into info(AccountId,Datum,Timmar,Rast) Values(@AccountId,@Datum,@Timmar,@Rast)", con))
            {
               DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountId", ACCOUNT_ID_SOURCE);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", now);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timmar", textBox2.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rast", textBox3.Text);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               MessageBox.Show("Sparat!");
               con.Close();
            }
```

now I have tried to use to get the user input that they typed to form2 with no luck.

```
               var frm1 = new Form1(); //Form2
               string ACCOUNT_ID_SOURCE = frm1.UserText; //Form2

               public string UserText { get; private set; } //form1
               UserText = this.user_txt.Text; //form1
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one?

Sol 1. Set a userid as a Form2's constructor parameter.

```
readonly string ACCOUNT_ID_SOURCE;
public Form2(string aUserID)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     ACCOUNT_ID_SOURCE = aUserID;
}
```

Sol 2. Make user information static class.

1) Class

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public static UserInfo instance = new UserInfo();
    public string LogInID { get; set; }
}
```

2) Form 1

```
UserInfo.instance.LogInID = "MyID";
```

3) Form 2

```
UserInfo.instance.LogInID; // Use this property
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I think there's a missunderstanding. I am trying to get the AccountId that is already set in the database and not from just 1 account but the account that is currently logged in/has logged in. Thanks!

Comment: i thought you get user id in form1 and use it in form2. in this case make a static user class and save it which get from database . you can use it in any class without using database :D . sorry for my misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

try this create a new class

```
 public class UserModel
   {
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

then in form1 in a button click event

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost; Initial   Catalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=True"))
        {
        //here your code to retrieve data from database
        userModel.FirstName = "";
        userModel.LastName = "";
        userModel.IdUser = 1;
        }           


        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(userModel);
        this.Hide();
        frm2.Show();
    }
```

and in your form2

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private UserModel UserObject { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Form2(UserModel userModel)
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        this.UserObject = userModel;

    }

    private void btnSaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into info(AccountId,Datum,Timmar,Rast) Values(@AccountId,@Datum,@Timmar,@Rast)", con))
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountId", UserObject.IdUser);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timmar", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rast", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Sparat!");
            con.Close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Same here I am trying to get a AccounrId that is set in the database and not just 1 id. The id of the account that just logged in. My try was totally wrong. I think I have to do something with a database query. Correct me if I am wrong. Also thanks!